# Java to CSV with Smooks

Tags: java, csv, smooks

Is there a way Smooks could generate a CSV file based on a java instance?

I am looking for something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  Employee emp = new Employee();
  emp.setName("abc");
  emp.setSalary(12312);
  /* set other emp fields */

  smooks.filterSource(.....);
}

CSV Output: "abc","12312", .............
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look at Smooks documentation [here](http://www.smooks.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=V1.5%3aSmooks_v1.5_User_Guide#Java_to_Text_.28XML.2C_CSV.2C_EDI_etc.29), it is done by wrapping your bean with `JavaSource` object - example can be found [here](https://github.com/smooks/smooks/blob/v1.5.1/smooks-examples/java-to-xml/src/main/java/example/Main.java)

Then you can use `FreeMarker` template to transform Java Object into desired format - [look here](http://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/transforming-xml-to-csv-via-xslt/)

**update**
Working example can be found [here at github](https://github.com/MaciejDobrowolski/SmooksJavaToCsvExample/tree/master)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The example is about java to xml. And I also checked their documentation but I cannot find anything about writing .csv files.. or maybe I missed something.

Comment: @user1919204 it is done by custom freemarker template - see updated answer

Comment: I have checked and it seems this is the way. Thanks for help! If you have a good example (better than the one from Smooks doc), please share.